# Как правильно задать вопрос в цикле do while, чтобы получать нужное число

Tags: c++, cs50

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Создаем переменные для высоты, пробелов и #
    int height;
    int spaces;
    int hashes;
    int hashes1;
    do
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    //Устанавливаем условия, где высота меньше 1 и больше 8, тогда повторяем цикл
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);
    //Создаем строки, i=1, останавливаемся когда i <= заданной высоте,прибавляем к i+1
    for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++)
    {
        //Создаем столбцы пробелов в цикле, пробел = высоте-1, стоп если пробел = 0, цикл пробел-1
        for (spaces = (height - i); spaces > 0; spaces--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        //Создаем столбцы хешей, # = 1, стоп если # = высоте, цикл #+1(обратить внимание,что i в ())
        for (hashes = 1; hashes <= (i); hashes++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("  ");
        //в конце строки не забываем добавить\n
        for (hashes1 = 1; hashes1 <= (i); hashes1++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //возвращаем к значению false
    return 0;
```

Comment: do {...} while (!(height >= 1 && height <= 8));

Comment: Я не правильно задал вопрос, дело в том что проходя курс на cs50, я не смог подключиться к #include <cs50.h> базе данных, а в ней как раз находиться функция get_int, которая у меня не работает, я поменял IDA и не смог найти замену этой строке, поэтому обратился сюда, хотелось бы узнать в какой БД есть такая же или похожая функция, ну и на крайний случай, как я могу заменить строку height = get_int("Height: ") ?